# When should I use Keycloak Gatekeeper?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-connect, keycloak-gatekeeper

I am really new to this authentication stuff. So from what I understand, Keycloak is used for authentication and authorization, and to use it you need what is called an adapter. After googling and reading their documentation (https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html), I understand that Keycloak Gatekeeper is a generic adapter.

So my questions are:

1. Do Keycloak Gatekeeper only used when developing with languages which adapters are not provided by Keycloak?
2. If I am about to make an app with Node.js, is it better for me to use the provided Node.js adapter rather than Keycloak Gatekeeper.

Comment: Keycloak is a Access management tool, i.e. it provides authentication, authorization, and federation, that what it does best, everything else can be considered as secondary tools, you can run your setup wiithout gatekeeper whatever language you are using, check keycloak github repo they provide ample examples about how to conenct it to your app